# How to compare a list of row value with one value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare a value with a list of value in for loop and show a single error message.

e.g.

I have 5 rows with 5 amount as a and one single amount value to compare 
if one case fails its false only not true

```
var principalrowLen = $(".principalrow").length;                        
for(i=0;i<principalrowLen;i++){
    var amountfiled = "amtTottal"+i;
    var amountvalu = $("#"+amountfiled).val().substring(1, $("#"+amountfiled).val().length);            

    amtfinal = 
}

if(amountvalu > toamt){                             
    var amountCompMsg ="error msg";
    $('#alert-warning-title').html("error msg");
    $('#alert-warning-body').html(amountCompMsg);
    $('#alert-warning').modal('show');
    $('#alert-warning').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("html").removeClass("modalOpen");
    })
    $('#alert-warning').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $("html").addClass("modalOpen");
    })
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Also, it helps if your code is complete and without errors...

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the "break" loop. You may need to compare each value with the "toamt" variable and if the "amountvalue" is greater than the value, you need to show the error message **FIRST** and then, **break** the loop.

```js
let toamt = 0; // whatever you intend, I don't know where you get it.
var principalrowLen = $(".principalrow").length;                        
for(i=0;i<principalrowLen;i++){
    var amountfiled = "amtTottal"+i;
    var amountvalue = $("#"+amountfiled).val().substring(1, $("#"+amountfiled).val().length);            
    if(amountvalu > toamt){                             
      var amountCompMsg ="error msg";
      $('#alert-warning-title').html("error msg");
      $('#alert-warning-body').html(amountCompMsg);
      $('#alert-warning').modal('show');
      $('#alert-warning').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $("html").removeClass("modalOpen");
      })
      $('#alert-warning').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
          $("html").addClass("modalOpen");
      });
      break; // the "break" command stops the loop.
    }
}
```